# Intermittent Windows Installer error 2753

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am writing this for whoever may have the same problem. I have a very simple installer package: WIX, 1 feature, 4 components, 1 custom action, no UI. Error 2753 "The File ... is not marked for installation." appears sometimes on first installation after uninstallation. Second attempt at installation is always successful.

The Windows Installer log shows:

Unsuccessful install, Error 2753:

> Feature: ProductFeature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Advertise;
>   **Action: Advertise**

Successful install:

> Feature: ProductFeature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;
>   **Action: Local**

Answer (score 1):

I stopped getting 2753 after adding these feature attributes:

```
Absent="disallow" AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local" TypicalDefault="install"
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is related to custom actions. The most likely reason is that you are running that file as a custom action, but as the error says "the file isn't marked for installation" so how can it run it as a custom action? This seems to be related to the feature not being installed - if you don't install the feature containing that file then it can't run it as a custom action. The other reason this message appears is when the custom action file isn't going to be installed because there is a higher version of the file on the system. Again, it's saying that this file in the MSI isn't being installed so it cannot run it as a custom action.

One solution is to always install the feature. The other is to run it as a CA from the Binary table.

Comment: That's correct - it is a custom action, and before the change (Absent="disallow" AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local" TypicalDefault="install") Windows Installer would sometimes decide not to install the one and only feature. There is no UI, so it was not as if the user decided not to install this feature, and this error only occurred after uninstall - there was no higher version of that file on the system, and on the second attempt it would get installed.

Answer (score -1):

I have 2753 when i have added

```
 Level
```

to  i just forgot to remove it and this was te reason.